# ASP.net MVC core RedirectToPage error - specify root relative path error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I want to redirect to a razor page from a normal controller action like this:

```
return RedirectToPage("Edit", new { id = blogId });
```

I have already a razor page named "Edit" which is working when navigating to it normally:
[image]

With `RedirectToPage` I get the following error:

> InvalidOperationException: The relative page path 'Edit' can only be
>   used while executing a Razor Page. Specify a root relative path with a
>   leading '/' to generate a URL outside of a Razor Page.

Any idea how to specify that path?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error already gave you the answer: You should add the leading '/' at the start and specify a relative path to your razor page. So you should have

```
return RedirectToPage("/BlogPosts/Edit", new { id = blogId });
```

Instead of

```
return RedirectToPage("Edit", new { id = blogId });
```

Notice the difference between **"/BlogPosts/Edit"** and **"Edit"**. `RedirectToPage` method expects a **path** to your razor page (based on your image the relative path is **"/BlogPosts/Edit"**) starting to the root folder which is `Pages` by default.

**Note:** Starting with Razor Pages 2.0.0, [redirecting to "sibling" pages works as well](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6083). In other words, if you have a page at `/BlogPosts/View`, it could redirect to `/BlogPosts/Edit` with `RedirectToPage("Edit", new { id = blogId })`, without specifying a rooted path.

Comment: Great, "/BlogPosts/Edit" did it, I expected that it works like RedirectToAction, where you just indicate the Action/Page name