# ASP.NET MVC and Razor Navigation in one project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor-pages

I have a menu system that calls ASP.NET MVC controllers without any problem. I want to call Razor pages from the same menu structure.

The system is using default ASP.NET MVC navigation thus defaulting to `/Views/etc.`
How do I switch to `/Pages/etc` for the Razor pages?

I tried setting the path to the page like this

```
./Pages    or     ../Pages     or     ~/pages
```

I have tried to use

```
return RedirectToPage("../Pages/Etc");
```

in the controller to call the Razor page. Again same issue with the default ASP.NET MVC navigation being imposed.

Comment: May I ask to show your code and where is the problem is exactly located to be able to help?

Comment: May be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51058793/asp-net-mvc-core-redirecttopage-error-specify-root-relative-path-error would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The value passed in to the `RedirectToPageResult` methods is relative to the current page, unless it is prefixed with a forward slash (`/`) in which case it is relative to the *Pages* folder (https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/action-results)

The *Pages* folder name should not be included in that value. So if you wanted to redirect to a page named *About*, located in the *Pages* folder, you just pass in the name of the page:

```
return RedirectToPage("/About");
```